# boost system make_error_code of type errc::timed_out has message of "Unkown error"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-system

Why does the following code output "Unknown error"?  I expect some other message like "operation timed out" or other descriptive error.

OS: Windows 7
      boost: 1.57

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/system/system_error.hpp"

void main()
{
    boost::system::error_code ec = make_error_code(boost::system::errc::timed_out);
    auto message = ec.message();
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: please post minimal complete example. That means something I can compile without having to guess.

Comment: code updated - thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you check include paths, library paths and project settings.

I have corrected the program (main must return an int) and compiled under clang:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/system/system_error.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::system::error_code ec = make_error_code(boost::system::errc::timed_out);
    auto message = ec.message();
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}
```

command line:

```
c++ -std=c++14 -I${HOME}/local/include -L${HOME}/local/lib -lboost_system
```

result:

```
Operation timed out
```

My boost installation is installed to the prefix ${HOME}/local

Comment: I think this may be a Windows thing.

Comment: @klmurphy72 have you tried assigning the error to an error_condition rather than an error_code?

Comment: I changed from error_code to error_condition and the result is the same.  This seems correct to me as the error value and the category remained unchanged.  At least that is how I understand it.  Either method ends up in "generic_error_category::message(int ev)".